# YouTube video with watch_popup redirects to "Walking Blind" by </LQ>

Tags: hyperlink, youtube

Whenever I open a Youtube link in the following format:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=xxx`

I get redirected specifically to `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bwf1vJGdHxg`

This happens on Android, when the link is opened in the YouTube app. If I click the link using Samsung's Browser, which opens YouTube links in a new tab instead of the app, I get the video I expect.

I've tried several versions of links including:

```
    https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx
    https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=xxx
    https://www.youtube.com/v/xxx
```

Only the watch_popup version seems to give me the issue, but there shouldn't be an issue at all...This occurs consistently with tons of videos, and based on the comments on the video, I'm not the only one experiencing this. It does not seem to be an issue on iOS, Chrome, or MacOS devices.